# Why are inline elements inside anchor tags not filling height of anchor, when anchor is flex item?

Tags: html, css

Consider the below code:

```css
.container {
   display: flex;
   background: red;
   align-items: center;
}
.inner {
   background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a>
    <span class="inner">Test<span>
  </a>
</div>
```

The span is not filling the height of the anchor (you see the red below the bottom edge of the blue box).

Why is CSS behaving that way and how can it be fixed?

---

**EDIT**

The question above stems from the following code, which does not have a span but suffers from the same problem (i.e. the inside of the anchor element does not fill the height of the anchor):

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background: red;
}

svg {
  height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a>
  Test
    <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="arrow-right" class="svg-inline--fa fa-arrow-right fa-1px " role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512" style="display: inline-block;"><path fill="currentColor" d="M438.6 278.6c12.5-12.5 12.5-32.8 0-45.3l-160-160c-12.5-12.5-32.8-12.5-45.3 0s-12.5 32.8 0 45.3L338.8 224 32 224c-17.7 0-32 14.3-32 32s14.3 32 32 32l306.7 0L233.4 393.4c-12.5 12.5-12.5 32.8 0 45.3s32.8 12.5 45.3 0l160-160z"></path></svg>
  </a>
</div>
```

This is what it looks like in Chrome DevTools, when inspecting the text inside the anchor element (the red box):

[image]

Comment: Can only reproduce in Firefox, not Chrome. Applying `display: inline-block` to the span appears to fix it in FF.

Comment: @CBroe I om on Chrome (the latest) and see red below the blue. Adding `display: inline-block` to the `span` does indeed seem to fix it. Any idea why?

Comment: Clarification: I placed the `span` there just to add background color and show the problem. Normally, I do not have a `span`, only free text inside the anchor element. Is there a solution then?

Comment: _"Is there a solution then?"_ - to what actual problem then? You asked about _"inline elements inside anchor tags not filling height of anchor"_, and now it turns out the inline elements don't actually exist.

Comment: @CBroe The OP shows a minimal reproducible example. In my actual code, there is free text inside the anchor, together with an SVG arrow sitting right next to the free text (also inside the anchor). In that scenario, just like in the OP, the inside of the anchor does not fill the height of the anchor. Coming back to the OP, why does the `inline` span box decide to be less tall than the surrounding `inline` anchor box?

Comment: Made an edit to the question, showing the issue as it actually occurred (the original question, above the edit, is a *minimal reproducible example*).

Comment: Okay _that_ problem stems from the fact that the default `vertical-align` value for that SVG element is `baseline`. Set it to something like `bottom`.

Comment: @CBroe Unfortunately not. Try it yourself, changing the `vertical-align` on the SVG will only move the SVG around, it will not make the text stretch the height of the anchor (which also means the text will not be centered in the anchor). Just try it out and you will see.

Comment: _"it will not make the text stretch the height of the anchor"_ - yeah, same as when flexbox is not involved in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by the difference between the rendered height of the text - top of the ascent to the bottom of the descent - which depends on the font metrics, and the line height, which does not.

Because the default line height is *almost* the same as text height for a typical font, the difference is small, but still noticeable. We can see much better what's going on if we give the `<a>` element a larger line-height value.

```css
.container {
   display: flex;
   background: red;
   align-items: center;
}
.inner, svg {
   background: blue;
}
a {
  line-height: 3;
  background: green;
}
svg {
  height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a>
    <span class="inner">Test</span>
  </a>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <a>
    Test
    <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="arrow-right" class="svg-inline--fa fa-arrow-right fa-1px " role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512" style="display: inline-block;">
      <path fill="currentColor" d="M438.6 278.6c12.5-12.5 12.5-32.8 0-45.3l-160-160c-12.5-12.5-32.8-12.5-45.3 0s-12.5 32.8 0 45.3L338.8 224 32 224c-17.7 0-32 14.3-32 32s14.3 32 32 32l306.7 0L233.4 393.4c-12.5 12.5-12.5 32.8 0 45.3s32.8 12.5 45.3 0l160-160z"></path>
    </svg>
  </a>
</div>
```

Block containers that establish an inline formatting context, like the `<a>` element when the `.container` div is `display:flex`, or the span when it's assigned `display:inline-block`, take the sum of line heights of the lines they contain as their height, rather than the height of the rendered text as the inline elements and text sequences do.

You can experiment with the line-height value of the `<a>` element to see if you can get a value that works well for your font, but there's currently no way in CSS for the line-height to be derived from the font metrics. There is a draft CSS specification that may allow it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
[image]

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background: red;
}

a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1;
}

svg {
  height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a>

  Test

    <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="arrow-right" class="svg-inline--fa fa-arrow-right fa-1px " role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512" style="display: inline-block;"><path fill="currentColor" d="M438.6 278.6c12.5-12.5 12.5-32.8 0-45.3l-160-160c-12.5-12.5-32.8-12.5-45.3 0s-12.5 32.8 0 45.3L338.8 224 32 224c-17.7 0-32 14.3-32 32s14.3 32 32 32l306.7 0L233.4 393.4c-12.5 12.5-12.5 32.8 0 45.3s32.8 12.5 45.3 0l160-160z"></path></svg>
  </a>
</div>
```

```css
  .container {
       display: flex;
       background: red;
       align-items: center;
      }
   
   a {
      display: flex;
      flex: 1;
   }
   
   .inner {
      flex: 1;
      background: blue;
   }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a>
    <span class="inner">Test<span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Sten. That solves the initial problem, but does not answer *why* it behaves that way (links to spec etc). Any idea? Moreover, if you check the edit, the solution does not address the underlying issue. Do you have a solution that works for the edit?

Comment: Ive added another one with the svg, does that help get to where u want to go? IM not completely sure the question.

Comment: Thanks, but if you check the text (*Test*) out with DevTools, in your answer, you can see that it does not stretch the height of the anchor.

Comment: I think it does... ill add an image

Comment: That's interesting. The text does not fill the height of the anchor in my browser. Are you on the latest version of Chrome? Is it working for you here as well (not working for me): https://codepen.io/magnusriga/pen/LYrdZpd

Comment: Im using brave here but chrome looks good to me as well.

Answer (score -2):

you need to tell the a-tag that it should grow. `flex-direction: row` is by the way the default.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  background: red;
}

a { flex-grow: 1; }

svg {
  height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a>
  Test
    <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="arrow-right" class="svg-inline--fa fa-arrow-right fa-1px " role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512" style="display: inline-block;"><path fill="currentColor" d="M438.6 278.6c12.5-12.5 12.5-32.8 0-45.3l-160-160c-12.5-12.5-32.8-12.5-45.3 0s-12.5 32.8 0 45.3L338.8 224 32 224c-17.7 0-32 14.3-32 32s14.3 32 32 32l306.7 0L233.4 393.4c-12.5 12.5-12.5 32.8 0 45.3s32.8 12.5 45.3 0l160-160z"></path></svg>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: That does not solve the issue, unfortunately. Growing is only along the inline-axis (row axis). Hover over the text (*Test*) in DevTools and you will see the issue as highlighted in the screenshot I added to the OP.